# Progress bar value events not reacting to value

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have used a timer, a progress bar and incremented the value by 2 on each timer tick. After that, "Main" should load, but it doesn't. Why? I did use a tracepoint which said the value was 100 and then the program exited with code 0.

```
Public Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    ProgressBar1.Increment(2)
    If ProgressBar1.Value = 100 Then
        Main.Show()
        Me.Close()
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: OK, it's kinda resolved now...But what was the cause of this?

Comment: Maybe you had closed the Solution Explorer window and just needed to reopen it?

Comment: All right, I figured out the solution and now I have a new problem. This worked before but then I backed up the project, reset the PC and put the VS files back how they were. Maybe this is the cause...

Comment: In the future, please don't edit your question to turn it into an entirely different question.  In a case like that, you should ask it as a new question.  If you decide that the old question is of no use, you can delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are using the **Application Framework** and you have selected the form that has that timer as the **Startup object** and you have the **Shutdown mode** set to the **When startup form closes** option (these are all options on the **Application** tab of the project properties designer window).  I suspect that is the case because those are the default settings for a new VB WinForm application project.  When you have your project configured that way, the application will automatically close when the startup form closes.  Therefore, when you call `Me.Close()` on the first form, the application terminates immediately, even when it has already shown another form.  One way to correct it is to change the **Shutdown mode** to the **When last form closes** option.